# Calcular la columna importacion de la tabla

Tags: java, c#, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-- (1ra imagen) Tengo un modal que me pasa los productos a la tabla cotizacion (2da imagen) donde el problema es que no me calcula correctamente la columna Import.

--la lógica es si la columna cantidad es mayor a la columna stock debe restar eso si lo calcula bien,
-- siguiendo la lógica caso contario si el stock es menor a la cantidad la columna Import lo debería de poner en 0 pero lo pone en menos(-) como muestra la imagen.

```js
        var artite = 0; var artimp = 0;
        $(document).on("click", ".agrpro", function () {
            row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
            artite = artite + 1;
                artcod = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(0)").text()); 
            var artmod = row.find("td:eq(1)").text();
            var artdes = row.find("td:eq(2)").text();
            var artmar = row.find("td:eq(3)").text();
            var artpsi = row.find("td:eq(4)").text();
            var artpci = row.find("td:eq(5)").text();
            var artsto = row.find("td:eq(8)").text(); //-- Stock
            var artcan = $("#cantAdd_" + artcod).val();        
            var total = parseFloat((artcan * artpsi).toFixed(2));
            var artplb = row.find("td:eq(6)").text();
            var totlib = parseFloat((artcan * artplb).toFixed(2));
            var artpkg = parseFloat(row.find("td:eq(7)").text());
            var totklg = parseFloat((artcan * artpkg).toFixed(2));
/*            var cotimp = (artcan - artsto)*/

            if (artcan > artsto) {
                artimp = cotimp ;
            } else {
                artimp = 0;
            }

            //for (let artite = 0; artite < 5; artite++) {
            //    console.log(artite); // Imprime los números del 0 al 4
            //}

            var contbod =
                   `<tr class="table-responsive-sm">
                    <td class='text-center cotite'>${artite}</td>
                    <td class='text-center'>${artcod}</td>
                    <td>${artmod}</td>
                    <td>${artdes}</td>
                    <td>${artmar}</td>
                    <td>${artpsi}</td>
                    <td>${artpci}</td>
                    <td>${artsto}</td>
                    <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class="cotcan">${artcan}</td>
                    <td>${artimp}</td>
                    <td style="background-color: lemonchiffon; color:#660000; font-weight: bold" class='subtotal'>${total}</td>
                    <td>${artplb}</td>
                    <td class="cottlb">${totlib}</td>
                    <td>${artpkg}</td>
                    <td  class="cottkg">${totklg}</td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn_remove btn btn-xs btn-danger ml-1"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>Eliminar</button></td>
                    </tr>`;
            $("#tabCot tbody").append(contbod);
            document.getElementById("TxtSer").value = final;
           /* $('#tabCot').dataTable();*/
            calsum()
            elifil()
        })
```

-- Mi código es: